# undefined method `query_options' for nil:NilClass, resque, unicorn, Rails 4, mysql

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, unicorn, resque

I get this error when i try to send an update mail.

```
 undefined method `query_options' for nil:NilClass

/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:218:in `execute'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:300:in `execute_and_free'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:461:in `columns'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:114:in `block in prepare_default_proc'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `yield'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `default'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:208:in `columns'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:217:in `columns_hash'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `block in valid?'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `each'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `all?'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `valid?'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:18:in `method_missing'
/home/user_name/work/app_name/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:12:in `update_message'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1485230712795781007__process_action__callbacks'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:503:in `process'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/resque_mailer-2.2.6/lib/resque_mailer.rb:48:in `new'
/home/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@app_name/gems/resque_mailer-2.2.6/lib/resque_mailer.rb:48:in `perform'
```

We are using Rails 4, unicorn 4.7 and resque 1.25.
For sending emails on the application we use different mailer. 
The recovery email that uses the object to send the emails, works fine, but the email that sends the profile update, which queries the user by id, does not work and throws the above error.

This is the unicorn config:

```
worker_processes 1

working_directory "correct/path" # available in 0.94.0+

listen "correct/path", :backlog => 64

timeout 30

pid "correct/path"

stderr_path "correct/path"
stdout_path "correct/path"

preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

   old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"

   if old_pid != server.pid
   begin
     sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
     Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
     rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
     end
   end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

end
```

I have tried various answer from stack overflow, or Github issues with no result.

Comment: As trace says, issue is in `user_mailer.rb:12:in 'update_message'` - have you checked it

Comment: Sounds like the caller expects `MySQL::Client` instance rather than `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`.

Comment: @WandMaker, here is the method:  `def update_message(user,old_email)
  @user = User.find_by_id(user)
  -- mail sending code --
 end`

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the problem, I had to restart the worker(s) after removing the octopus gem.

That error message is because octopus does not work very well out of the box with unicorn so I did configured it, but I forgot to close the worker, and it kept the octopus setting thus throwing this error.

Unfortunately I could not find a good way to use octopus with our applications because we got this error, that as far as I could see is related to Resque, more precisely when any of the workers forks a process, it fails to connect to an outside database, ex: x model connecting to y database., which works well for the application using octopus_connect, but not for the workers.

Our solution was to use instead taskrabbit/makara as the connection proxy.